# Resize the Member Variable inside the Dynamically Allocated Object in C++

Tags: c++, object

I am wondering what would happen if you resized a member variable, say `vector`, in a dynamically allocated object. For instance:

```
class A
{
public:
    vector<int> x;

    void expand()
    {
        vector<int> y = { 1, 2, 3 };
        x = y;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A* a = new A;
    cout << sizeof(*a) << endl;
    a->expand();
    for (auto v : a->x)
        cout << v << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Since the size of the allocated object `A` is already determined by the time of `new`, would this operation result in undefined behavior? Since the compiler does not know the actual size of `x` when the allocation happens, the `expand()` should not work. If yes, how should I get around from this problem? Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: check `sizeof(v)` for vector<int> v of different sizes. Is using a vector undefined behaviour?

Comment: If you by "size" means `sizeof`, then no matter what you do with the vector the size will change of either `A`, `a`, `*a` *or* of `a->x`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've read your comment five times and still it has no sense to me. The size will NOT change, will it?

Comment: `a->x.size()` will change, but `sizeof *a` will *not* change. Those two concepts are unrelated.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So your comments contradict each other. The first one states that if you do anything with "the vector" the size of `*a` is going to change. The second one states otherwise.

Comment: Okay, that was a typo, the size will ***not*** change is what I meant to say.

Comment: All objects of a given type `T` has the same size in terms of `sizeof`. If the expression `e` has type `T`, then `sizeof(e)` is equivalent to `sizeof(T)`.

Comment: The `vector` will do its own dynamic allocations as needed, and keep a pointer to that. And just like `a` doesn't change in size, neither does `x`.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to reason about `std::vector` implementation as it is compiler specific. Here is a very simple class that allows to store elements which number is unknown in compile time.

```
#include <iostream>

class TrivialExtendableArray
{
public:
    TrivialExtendableArray()
       : internalStorage(nullptr),
         size(0)
    {

    }

    ~TrivialExtendableArray()
    {
        if(internalStorage != nullptr)
        {
            delete []internalStorage;
        }
    }

    TrivialExtendableArray(const TrivialExtendableArray&) = delete;
    TrivialExtendableArray& operator=(const TrivialExtendableArray&) = delete;

     int* getPointer()
     {
         return internalStorage;
     }
     size_t getSize()
     {
         return size;
     }

     void addElement(int newElementValue)
     {
         int* newStorage = new int[size+1];

         std::copy(internalStorage, internalStorage + size, newStorage);

         if(internalStorage != nullptr)
         {
              delete []internalStorage;
         }
         newStorage[size] = newElementValue;

         size++;
         internalStorage = newStorage;
    }

    const int* begin() const
    {
         return internalStorage;
    }
    const int* end() const
    {
         return internalStorage + size;
    }

 private:
    int* internalStorage;
    size_t size;
 };

 std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const TrivialExtendableArray& array)
 {
     out << "{ ";
     for(const int* i = array.begin(); i != array.end(); i++)
     {
         out << *i << " "; 
     }
     return out << "}";
 }

 int main()
 {
     TrivialExtendableArray array;

     std::cout << "Empty TrivialExtendableArray on stack sizeof: " << sizeof(array) << ": " << array << std::endl;

     array.addElement(5);

     std::cout << "TrivialExtendable with one element on stack sizeof: " << sizeof(array) << ": " << array << std::endl;

     array.addElement(3);

     std::cout << "TrivialExtendable with two elements on stack sizeof: " << sizeof(array) << ": " << array << std::endl;

     array.addElement(3);

     std::cout << "TrivialExtendable with three elements on stack sizeof: " << sizeof(array) << ": " << array << std::endl;

 }
```

The result of this program may vary depending on compiler and architecture that you are using I've received something like that:

```
$ ./a.out 
Empty TrivialExtendableArray on stack sizeof: 16: { }
TrivialExtendable with one element on stack sizeof: 16: { 5 }
TrivialExtendable with two elements on stack sizeof: 16: { 5 3 }
TrivialExtendable with three elements on stack sizeof: 16: { 5 3 3 }
```

The size of a class is the same each time because the object of `TrivialExtendableArray` needs only to store pointer to allocated memory and the size of this memory. The number of elements does not change the size of this class' fields.

The `std::vector` uses very similar approach. Hence the size of `std::vector` objects do not change when you make any operation on them.